# GitLab: How to use ONLY Apache2 and skip nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, gitlab

I am running GitLab on Port 81 today and I need it to run on Port 80 or 443 so that I can access it from office. Problem is that I already host other services using Apache2 on both those ports.

I have tried for hours and hours to do a proxy forward of GitLab from Apache2 host:80/gitlab to host:81 (where nginx is hosting gitlab) without success. I just keep getting problems thanks to the added folder /gitlab in the URL.

So I am in the idea of selfhosting gitlab under my Apache2 server instead. I am thinking of this approach:

1. Create symlink to webroot of gitlab from /home/www/sites/gitlab
2. Set up a vhost in Apache on port 81 to point to above symlink.
3. Enable Apache2 to listen on port 81.
4. Verify that GitLab functions properly on port 81 using Apache2.
5. Once confirmed, set up a proxy forward from my Apache2 Port 80 under subdir /gitlab to forward to the new Apache2 Port 81 now hosting GitLab.

What I need to know now is:

1. Is it possible to completely host gitlab on your own Apache2?
2. What is necessary to enable in Apache2 virtual host dir? Or other configs? Ruby etc?
3. Where is the webroot of github index documents etc?
4. What do you think of permission issues? Will I see any problems?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: It amazes me why people insist on running multiple web services on a single host in this day of virtualization.